# JQuery Mobile enhanceWithin() function not working in Android Webview

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview, android-webview

I have an app running a website I have served locally on a Raspberry Pi. The enhance within function is enhancing a webpage after it gets html data from a php request. (to get it to work on the desktop, the page had to reload once then enhance the data)

```
success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $("#checkEntityList").html(data);
          if (!localStorage.getItem("reloadRooms1")) {
            localStorage.setItem("reloadRooms1", "true");
            location.reload();
            $("#checkEntityList").enhanceWithin();
          }
          else {
              $("#checkEntityList").enhanceWithin();
              localStorage.removeItem("reloadRooms1");
          }
```

This works perfectly fine on my laptop, but when I open the app, it will throw the error

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "Uncaught TypeError:
>   $(...).enhanceWithin is not a function", source:
>   http://---.---.---/setup.html (21)

enhanceWithin works perfectly fine in other webpages in the app, but for some reason will not work on this specific page. Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reloading page will initialize all widgets of jQM, so you don't need to initialize them manually.

Comment: And by the way, enhance widgets on `.done()` to avoid racing.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem!